# Programming atmega328p's UART on arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, avr

I am attempting serial transmission in arduino by programming the Serial communication registers of its atmega328p directly (I know there is a ready made serial communication library in arduino but I want try programming atmega328p myself).

I am trying to send a character 'a' to a serial lcd by using tx pin of arduino.
I have referred to several resources online and have arrived at the following code:

```
#define BAUDRATE(BAUD) (((F_CPU/(BAUD*16UL)))-1)


class serials
    { 
        serials()
        {
            UBRR0H = BAUDRATE(9600) >> 8;
            UBRR0L = BAUDRATE(9600);

            UCSR0A &= ~_BV(U2X0);
            UCSR0B |= _BV(TXEN0) | _BV(RXEN0);
            UCSR0C |= _BV(UCSZ00) | _BV(UCSZ01);
        }
         void transmit(unsigned char);
};

void serials::transmit(unsigned char data)
    {


                loop_until_bit_is_clear(UCSR0A,UDRE0);  
                UDR0 = data;
    }



void loop() 
{
    serials lcdtransmit;

        lcdtransmit.transmit(254);
        lcdtransmit.transmit(1);
        lcdtransmit.transmit(254);
        lcdtransmit.transmit(128);
        lcdtransmit.transmit('a');

        while(1);
}
```

However, when I run this code,

1. There is no output on the lcd display.
2. The tx pin is always high.
3. When the `while(1)` is not present, there seems to output at the 'tx pin' but with no output on the lcd display.

Is there any error in the code written for serial transmission ?

Comment: `while(1)` in `loop()` is usually not a good idea. One reason is that the chip may have a hardware watchdog, and the Arduino library normally resets it outside of `loop()`. If you never return from `loop()`, the watchdog is never reset, and thus will cause the chip to reboot. You should ensure this code only runs once by simply using a global `bool`.

Comment: @DarkFalcon Or use `setup()` to have some code executed only once at program startup.

Comment: I have even erased the while loop from the code, but even then its not responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are using the 328p on an Arduino you should assume the boot-loader have already written to the UART registers before you reach your code. Hence the UCSR0B and UCSR0C registers should be fully assigned rather than just masking in your set bits.